# How to break a string based on a word in a txt file with batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-manipulation

I have been reading around here for several days, and I have found many shared scripts but it doesn't appear that those shared here can help me with my request, I have also looked online and I can't seem to find how to do this

If you have a question here that was already ask, that will do exactly what I have ask, please provide a link and feel free to close my question, and I am sorry if I asked a repeated question

my file is under word wrap, and I would like to find the word code and return it, like if I placed the cursor in front of the word code and I press enter

```
Version model 173838r8, "code": data of strings, "code": data of strings, "code": data of strings,
```

.

```
Version model 173838r8,
"code": data of strings,
"code": data of strings,
"code": data of strings,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q75792000.txt"

REM (
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%e"
 CALL :process
)

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "line=%line:, =,|%"
:processloop
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=|" %%b IN ("%line%") DO ECHO %%b&SET "line=%%c"&IF DEFINED line GOTO processloop
GOTO :eof
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

Note that if the filename does not contain separators like spaces, then both `usebackq` and the quotes around `%filename1%` can be  omitted.

I've made a number of assumptions for lack of clarity, mainly that `|` is never encountered in the source data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty confusing to me... This phrase: *"my file is under word wrap, and I would like to find the word code and return it, like if I placed the cursor in front of the word code and I press enter"* have no sense...

The question is *"How to break a string based on a word"* but you didn't specified *which word* is used to break the string!

I *assumed* that you want to "break a string at `,`  (comma-space) delimiters":

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for %%n in (^"^
%Don't remove this line%
^") do echo !line:, =,%%~n!
)
```

This code just replaces `comma-space` by `comma-newline` characters...

**EDIT:** *Test output added*

This is my input file:

```
Version model 173838r8, "code": data of strings, "code": data of strings, "code": data of strings,
```

and this is the output:

```
Version model 173838r8,
"code": data of strings,
"code": data of strings,
"code": data of strings,
```

Comment: Yes, after the comma, or word, I'm not looking to make it prettify like a Json, but just pushed down, instead straight across

Comment: For me (and for most other people) the _words_ in your text are: `Version`, `model`, `173838r8,`, `"code":`, `data`, `of`, `strings,`, etc. That is: a group of characters delimited by space. If you use a _nonstandard definition_ for "word", then you should first explain it (if you want that others understand what you want)...

Comment: Anyway, did this code get the desired result? If so, you should check its green check-mark to inform others that this question was solved. Otherwise, you should explain how this code failed in order to improve it (that is how this site works)...

Comment: Hello Aacini, and Thank you but for some reason none seem to work, I made a practice txt based on my question, and I can't seem to make any of the offered scripts to work, maybe the problem is here `^") do echo !line:, =,%%~n!` maybe I'm not to sure

Comment: Did you made your practice txt _from the data **you posted** in the question_? Please, be aware that we can only have the data you posted to complete tests, so please, you should do _the same_ than we!  See the **EDIT** in my answer...

Comment: Yes I did, just to make sure I tested it correctly, didn't want to say it failed if I didn't test correctly, my data is very large and not easy to share, but what I have is about 80% accurate, but as long as it finds the `,` it should work